# jquery textbox value not showing in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Works great in all other browsers except IE9.Is there any fix?Have tried .attr("value") as well but it still does not work.

```
$searchbox.focus(function(e){  
        $(this).val("");  
});  
$searchbox.blur(function(e){  
      if($(this).val()=="")
           $(this).attr("value","Search For Music...");

});
```

Comment: Make sure your browser isn't running in "quirks mode".

Comment: missing a ) at the end of the `if` line

Comment: Yes missed the ) when I copied but that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$searchbox.focus(function(e){  
        $(this).val("");  
});  
$searchbox.blur(function(e){  
      if($(this).val(""))
           $(this).val("Search For Music...");

});
```

did you check like this?

but you want to clear text on focus and add text "Search For Music" if blank text, if so you can do like

```
$searchbox.focus(function(e){ 
    if($(this).val() == "Search For Music...")
        $(this).val("");  
});  
$searchbox.blur(function(e){  
      if($(this).val() == "")
           $(this).val("Search For Music...");

});
```

Comment: Yep, made a mistake when copied to stackoverflow.But the code is correct(updated).

Comment: I am trying to find a solution.$searchbox.val("Search for Music...") does only display an empty space where the text should be and then "...".

Comment: Does not work on my end.And I have no idea why. Please check wuerch[dot]net/music